# Why this?: \dotnet\ was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

On Windows 11, here's my batch file:

```
if "%orig_path%"=="" (
  set "orig_path=%path%"
) else (
  path %orig_path%
)

path %path%;D:\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_322\bin
set "JAVA_HOME=D:\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_322"
```

(I do this because I often need to switch between Java 8 and 11.)

On the very first line, I get this error message: `\dotnet\ was unexpected at this time.`

This is a reference to one of two elements in my current path:

`...C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;...`

I doubt the problem is the space character, because several elements before these also use a space character, so the culprit is probably the parentheses around `x86`.

(I'm not authorized to change that part of my path.)

I have read that I can fix this by changing the if statement to this:

`if [%orig_path%]==[] ...`

but that doesn't work either. That gives me this error:

`C:\WINDOWS was unexpected at this time.`

And I've read that I should say `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the start of the file, but that didn't change anything.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: We cannot replicate your issue because you've posted only a snippet of code which contains variables defined outside of the code and with no string values mentioned elsewhere in the question body. Please [Edit] your question to include a [mcve]; thank you.

Comment: and what does`path` in `path %orig_path%` do? is there a `path.exe` in your `%path%`?

Comment: @phuclv path is the DOS command for setting or showing your path. Typing path with no parameters shows your path. With a parameter, it sets the path. I believe it's a built-in command, so there's no executable file for it. Try it.

Comment: @Compo The only variable defined outside of the code is the path variable, which comes pre-defined when you open a command prompt. As for %orig_path%, this is the batch file that defines it.

Comment: If `%orig_path%` isn't already potentially defined why would you need an `if` command then? (You didn't use the same logic when defining `%JAVA_HOME%`). Regardless, just use ```If Not Defined orig_path (Set "orig_path=%Path%") Else Set "Path=%orig_path%"``` or ```If Defined orig_path (Set "Path=%orig_path%") Else Set "orig_path=%Path%"```.

Comment: The `if` command is there so I can run this script (and a parallel script that sets Java 11) multiple times, allowing me to switch between the two Java versions seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy-peasy.

Your code would be resolved to:

```
if "...Program Files (x86)\dotnet\..."=="" (
  set "orig_path=%path%"
) else (
  path ...Program Files (x86)\dotnet\...
)
```

and that `)` closes the `if`; cmd doesnt know what to do with the `\dotnet\...` so complains.

To fix:

```
if "%orig_path%"=="" (
  set "orig_path=%path%"
) else (
  path "%orig_path%"
)
```

or my preference

```
if defined orig_path (
  path "%orig_path%"
) else (
  set "orig_path=%path%"
)
```

Comment: You claimed that the ')' character closes the "if", but it looks like it doesn't close the if, it actually closes the "else". Because the only change you made was in the else clause. I'm not clear why the ')' character doesn't close the '(' character four characters before it, although I now see why the quotes in the fourth line fix the behavior in the first line.

Comment: OK. It closes the `else` clause of the `if` statement. Batch doesn't keep count of the parentheses - are the parentheses simply data or syntactic elements? In your original code, `else path %orig_path%` would also have worked as the `else` clause doesn't have a parenthesis to close. `Cmd` needs the programmer to specify whether the `)` is data or syntax, as often happens in a `for`, and to mark the data `)` with an escape (`^)`). Here, the `)` is part of the variable's value, so enclosing that value in quotes causes batch to recognise it as a literal string, uninvolved with syntax

Comment: Thanks. I think the most important thing I learned here is that it parses the entire if-else structure before it evaluates the expression in the if clause, but after it completes the parameter substitution. That's why a fix in the fourth line was needed before the first line would execute at all. Before I knew that, I focused my attention on fixing that first line, which wasn't the problem.